# Slow LINQ query when using OrderByDescending on child property

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

```
var allUsers = GetAllUsers()
 .Where(x => x.UserStatusHistory
   .OrderByDescending(y => y.Created)
   .First().StatusId == (int) UserStatusEnum.Enabled);
```

I'm returning the above as an IQueryable but when I run `allUsers.Count();` it takes ~5 seconds, it should be pretty much instant. There are ~**2000** user records.

Is the LINQ is doing something inefficient like running a separate query for each user to calculate the first UserStatusHistory record?

```
edit to answer questions:

GetAllUsers() returns an IQueryable<User>
EF Core 1.1.1 is being used.
```

Comment: What does `GetAllUsers` return? A `List<User>` with all users?

Comment: To understand the problem you should look at the sql generated by EF. Redirect your database log to output window and you can see all queries executed by sql server.

Comment: Not sure how the sql translates, but you are ordering the UserStatusHistory. Possibly this creates a nested select query for each user record, which would explain the performance issue. At this point I am just guessing, but that is where I would look first. I would suggest you try to make the same result with a join

Comment: If you really execute sql (and not using `Linq-To-Objects` because `GetAllUsers` returns a list) you should also look at the execution plan to see if you can optimize the query. Maybe an index is missing.

Comment: Well that First might be a problem try single instead

Comment: @FilipCordas: Why that? Both are same apart from the fact that `Single` needs to select two instead of one records to check if there is another. In that case it will throw an exception.

Comment: The question really lacks a context. Query providers process LINQ queries differently. You need to specify the ORM used, e.g. EF6, EF Core (+ version) etc.

Comment: After thinking about it, and making some fair assumptions, perhaps you should try: `var alUsers = GetAllUsers().Where(x => x.UserStatusHistory.Any(y => y.Created && y.StatusId == (int)UserStatusEnum.Enabled));`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am not sure if that is true with all providers I remember having problem with some IQueriable(I am not sure what it was) when query was being translated and First was loading things in memory and Single was not.

Comment: @FilipCordas: never heard of such an issue. Both should behave same regarding this. If `First`(or `Single`) is the last statement the query gets executed and the result is loaded into memory. But if it's part of the (sub)query then it's translated to sql. Maybe there was a bug in your provider or in the query itself.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are probably right, this was a long time ago

Comment: GetAllUsers() returns an `IQueryable<User>`.

Comment: EF Core 1.1.1 is being used.

Comment: @Filip - your partially right. `.First()` is returning an IEnumerable which I believe would cause the sql to be executed as it goes into memory. Though your suggestion to use `.Single()' as an alternative won't help.

Comment: @NigelGossage Could you try if this helps `from user in table
                        from status in user.UserStatusHistory.OrderBy(u => u.Created).Take(1)
                        where status.StatusId == 0
                        select user;`

Comment: Hi Nigel, try to dump the generated query using SQL Profiler as Hamlet suggested. it would be best start from there.

Comment: @Bagus using ANTS Performance profiler you can see it's executing the individual sort for each of the user records. This is the performance problem.

Comment: could you dump the generated query?

Comment: It's firing a UserStatusHistory
   .OrderByDescending query for each of the users returning in GetAllUsers() so there is infomation overload when looking at the debug window. The other thing I've looked at is using MoreLinq and MaxBy() but that doesn't play nicely.

Comment: @NigelGossage Did my query help with perf?

Comment: @Filip Cordas No, I voted it as useful as you were right about .First() being the problem.